# Is it possible to determine whether a certain function may be called when a passed-in callback function is executed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, callback

The question title basically says it all. I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tj2yf1ce/1/) Fiddle to make it easy to test. Here's the code:

```
var test = function(callback) {
    console.log("callback() might call alert()");
    callback();
}

test(function() {
    alert("one");
});
```

Comment: This is not feasible in general. What if the the `alert()` is inside an `if`. There's no way for the caller to know whether the condition will be true or false, so it can't tell whether it will be called. This is equivalent to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: @Barmar: You're right...but keeping it as simple as possible, is there any way to peek at what's inside of the callback function being passed in? Even just to see how many times `alert()` is referenced (even if it never gets called)?

Comment: @Barmar: I've changed the question a bit in response to your comment.

Comment: If you convert the function to a string, you'll get the source code. You can count the number of times `alert` appears.

Comment: This question sounds like a huge [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/183280). Why would you want to do that (you cannot)?

Comment: @Bergi: Who says I'm trying to solve a specific problem? Asking a question simply to gain a deeper understanding of a language should not be frowned upon, it should be encouraged (as long as the question is well-defined).

Comment: @David: It just looked like so, being rather specific about `alert` and `callback`. Also, this problem is rather language-agnostic, so I didn't see how it would give a deeper understanding of JavaScript. But Barmar's comment had covered that already, it's impossible to determine what a function does without basically executing it. And no, JavaScript does not have any introspection features necessary to see what values are referenced from a function (scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a function to a string returns the source code, you can search that with a regular expression.

```
var test = function(callback) {
    if (callback.toString().test(/\balert\s*\(/) {
        console.log("callback might call alert()");
    callback();
};
```

This isn't perfect, though. It won't work with:

```
var foo = alert;
test(function() {
    foo("Fooled you!");
});
```

It could also get a false positive if `alert(` appears in a string.

Comment: Very cool. I didn't realize the `toString()` could be used on functions to return the source code.

Comment: I didn't either. I googled _javascript source code of function_ and it pointed me to the MDN entry for `.toString()`. It also found `.toSource`, but that's non-standard. What did you google before you came here?

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine function alert

```js
 function alert(str) {
  console.log('Somebody call alert:'+str);
 }
```

But IMHO it can't be definitely checked before call.